# Vector Space Orientation

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, manifolds, group-isomorphism, vector-space-isomorphism

I am trying to understand this definition...

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $m\in \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$. Two bases on $V$, which are descrived by two isomorphisms $\psi,\phi: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow V$, are said to have the same **orientation** iff $det(\psi^{-1} \circ\phi)>0.$ Otherwise, they have the **opposite orientation**.

I am having a hard time picturing this in a graph and understanding what isomorphism is. I slightly remember group isomorphism from abstract algebra but I am having trouble with this concept in my analysis class. How does the determinent of an inverse function composed with another function play a role here?

Comment: Have you seen this article?
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)

Comment: It might be best to first understand isomorphisms clearly before worrying about orientation.

Comment: Instead of trying to understand this abstractly, is there an example I can follow where I can see the isomorphism and the determinent part?

Comment: Simplest example that shows two bases with opposite orientations: Take $V = \mathbb R^2$ with two ordered bases $\cal B = \{\hat i, \hat j\}$ and $\cal B' = \{\hat j, \hat i\}$. The isomorphism that maps $(V, \cal B)$ to $(V, \cal B')$ is $f(x) = Ax$ where $x = [x_1, x_2]^t$ and $A$ is the matrix \begin{equation*}A = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1& 0\end{bmatrix}.\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example to make things a little more concrete.  Let $V$ be the vector space of all $2 \times 2$ real symmetric matrices.  (So $V$ has dimension $3$.)

Let $\phi:\mathbb R^3 \to V$ be defined by
$$
\phi(x,y,z) = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ y & z \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\phi$ is an isomorphism that maps the standard ordered basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ to the basis
$\alpha = \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right).$

Let $\Psi:\mathbb R^3 \to V$ be defined by 
$$\Psi(x,y,z) = \begin{bmatrix} z & y \\ y & x \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\Psi$ is an isomorphism that maps the standard ordered basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ to the basis
$\beta = \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right).$

The function $\Psi^{-1} \circ \phi$ is given by
\begin{align}
(\Psi^{-1}\circ \phi)(x,y,z) &= \Psi^{-1}\left( \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ y & z \end{bmatrix} \right) \\
&= (z,y,x).
\end{align}
You can check that $\Psi^{-1}\circ \phi$ has a negative determinant, which shows that the ordered bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have opposite orientation.